# Xamarin Community Toolkit MediaElement not showing an Playback controls or play the video in the source UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.communitytoolkit

**Updated**  - This issue only happens on UWP - Works fine on Android haven't tested it on IOS. I would assume it would work just as fine. The issue is with `Xamarin.Community.Toolkit` not working with `UWP`

I've just started learning Xamarin for App development. I'm mostly running UWP for testing as emulators slow down my machine. After researching the best tool to play videos using Xamarin I found the `Xamarin Community Toolkit`. Followed the basic steps required to get `MediaElement` on screen and added basic properties to it.

I got the Xamarin tutorial basic video used in a tutorial inside the source. I know it works because you can copy the link and paste it into a browser and you'll get it playing.

After messing around with different versions I can't get this to work. No controls want to show up either nor the video itself. I have run out of ideas please someone HELP.

Running a blank template for this practice Hello World Project.
Using all of the latest versions possible. Project was created 20/09/2022 So I would assume everything latest version.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="HelloWorldXamarin.MainPage"
             Title="This is a Hello World Practice Project">

<xct:MediaElement Source="https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/5d93/a1eab4bf-3288-4faf-81c4-294402a85d93/XamarinShow_mid.mp4" 
                          BackgroundColor="LightBlue" 
                          HeightRequest="300"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          ShowsPlaybackControls="True"
                          AutoPlay="True"/>
```

This is what I get on my screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the situation you describe is actually a bug for UWP, and you can check this [link](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1171).

By the way, I test the code you provided. But It doesn't matter which version I change `Xamarin Community Toolkit` to.

Comment: Interesting situation we got here then. I did actually read that post but it was posted year ago so I would assume major version+ they would fix this issue, seems like not. Thanks for the answer.